# Confused on how to edit css for label

Tags: html, css

I have a radio button label (which I can not change)

```
<label class="gui-left" for="gui-form-shipping-external|liquid-delivery|delivery_zone_891_0">
                  Deliver Today
</label>
```

I need to change the following in css:

```
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: 400;
```

The class -> for is giving me a rough time...

Comment: Are you looking for `.gui-left[for='gui-form-shipping-external|liquid-delivery|delivery_zone_891_0']`? I'm lost by your question.

Comment: `the class for ...` what do you mean with that? the class is: `gui-left`. or do you mean the `for` attribute? There should be the ID of an input field that the label should be linked to. And most certainly: `gui-form-shipping-external|liquid-delivery|delivery_zone_891_0` would not be a valid id.

Comment: You don't seem to have enough information here. How are you try to change the CSS? Is this happening at runtime via Javascript? Are you trying to change CSS from an external file?

Comment: What CSS have you tried so far? How did it fall short? Why is `.gui-left{...}` not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```css
.gui-left[for='gui-form-shipping-external|liquid-delivery|delivery_zone_891_0'] {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

The `[for=...]` is a specific css selector syntax. See [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)